# How to append a string to NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i'm an absolute newbie with objective-c

with this code

```
NSMutableString *teststring;
[teststring appendString:@"hey"];
NSLog(teststring);
```

nothing gets displayed in the console.

Surely i'm doing something wrong here... :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change first line to

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [NSMutableString string];
```

Answer (score 58):

You need to create the string first.

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

[teststring appendString:@"hey"];

NSLog(teststring);
```

Now, it will print.

Comment: Please update your answer like @sly's to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: People used to create their project with ARC. So, compiler adds such instruction and nothing to worry.

Answer (score 9):

This line

```
NSMutableString *teststring;
```

simply establishes a pointer, but does not create anything. Instead, you need to create a new instance of `NSMutableString`, for example:

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[teststring appendString:@"hey"];
NSLog("%@", teststring);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sample:

```
NSMutableString *buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // retain count = 1. Because of the "alloc", you have to call a release later

[buffer appendString:@"abc"];
NSLog(@"1 : %@", buffer);
[buffer appendString:@"def"];
NSLog(@"2 : %@", buffer);

[buffer release]; // retain count = 0 => delete object from memory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *tag = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"hello <td> this is inside td </td> 000999 <><> ..<. ><> 00000 <td>uuuuu</td> vvvvv <td> this is also inside td </td>"];  
    NSRange open = [tag rangeOfString:@"<"]; 
    while(open.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSRange close = [tag rangeOfString:@">"]; 
        NSRange string = NSMakeRange(open.location, close.location-open.location+1);
        [tag replaceCharactersInRange:string withString:@""];               
        open =  [tag rangeOfString:@"<"];
        NSLog(@"%@",tag);
    }
```